# Allow angle braces for wp_kses '<' and '>'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried finding a solution for this, I am trying to use wp_kses where I have some css code, which includes angle braces < and > . But these gets replaced by "&gt"
How do I allow angle braces for wp_kses ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible; it would make rather little sense to begin with. The purpose of this function is to strip out unwanted HTML content, and only letting a set of allowed HTML _tags_ through. Making it let pass any arbitrary < and > through, would be counter-productive. Please expand a bit on the context here, what data are you getting and from where, that needs to be inserted into the HTML document?

Comment: So basically I need to output a source code of a website from the plugin, but the reviewers are asking me to escape the html code. This html code has javascript, css and html contents, js and css are dynamic and cannot be separately included from the plugin, it's just impossible to use wp_kses in this case

Comment: Then you perhaps need a different approach - use a DOM parser to parse the content first, and then re-assemble it into string form, using only "trusted" parts. Although that would probably still mean using content of script and style elements unchanged - which of course can be risky, if the source can't be fully trusted. Right now, this is simply too vague for any more specific advice.

Comment: The source can definitely be trusted, but the problem is wordpress review they want me to escape the html code which breaks styling and javascript errors all over the place, any ideas how I can overcome this, I have allowed html tags and html elements are working perfectly fine, problem is just css and js

Comment: _"The source can definitely be trusted"_ - says who? And who guarantees it will stay that way? _"but the problem is wordpress review"_ - so this is going to be a plugin released for use by the public? Right now, this really lacks some details.